# Correct Package Importing in a Pythonic Library Design?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a python project structured like this:

```
repo_dir/
----project_package/
--------__init__.py
--------process.py
--------config.py
----tests/
--------test_process.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty

`config.py` looks like this:

```
name = 'brian'
```

**USAGE**

I use the library by running `python process.py` from the `project/project/` directory, or by specifying the python file path absolutely. I'm running Python 2.7 on Amazon EC2 Linux.

When `process.py` looks like below, everything works fine and `process.py` prints `brian`.

```
import config
print config.name
```

When `process.py` looks like below, I get the error `ImportError: No module named project.config`.

```
import project.config
print config.name
```

When `process.py` looks like below, I get the error `ImportError: No module named project`. This makes sense as the same behavior from the previous example should be expected.

```
from project import config
print config.name
```

If I add these lines to `process.py` to include the library root in `sys.path`, all configurations above, work fine.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

**MY CONFUSION**

Many resources suggest setting up python libraries to import modules using `project.module_name`, but it doesn't seem like `sys.path` appending is standard, and seems weird that I need it. I can see that the sys.path append added my library root as a path in sys, but I thought that's what the `__init__.py` in my library root was supposed to do. What gives? What am I missing? I know Python importing creates lots of headaches so I've tried to simplify this as much as possible to wrap my head around it. I'm going crazy and it's Friday before a holiday. I'm bummed. Please help!!

**QUESTIONS**

How should I set up my libraries? How should I import packages? Where should I have `__init__.py` files? Do I need to append my library root to sys.path in every project? Why is this so confusing?

Answer (score 1):

Your project setup is alright. I renamed the directories just for clarity
in this example, but the structure is the same as yours:

```
repo_dir/

    project_package/
        __init__.py
        process.py
        config.py

    # Declare your project in a setup.py file, so that
    # it will be installable, both by users and by you.
    setup.py
```

When you have a module that wants to import from another module in
the same project, the best approach is to use relative imports. For example:

```
# In process.py
from .config import name

...
```

While working on the code on your dev box, do your work in a Python virtualenv,
and pip install your project in "editable" mode.

```
# From the root of your repo:
pip install -e .
```

With that approach, you'll never need to muck around with `sys.path` -- which
is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: Am I overcomplicating this by treating it like an installable python app? It's an internal application for our company and does not get distributed to lots of users, even internally. Do you think it's good practice to always treat relatively large python projects as installable packages?

Comment: @T.BrianJones Definitely design your package in the standard way, with a proper directory structure and setup.py file. Aside from some up-front learning (a one-time cost), creating the file and declaring your project's dependencies takes no more than a few minutes per project. There are many benefits to having a project be pip installable: you can share the code with colleagues or even the world; you can better debug strange scenarios; you have a formal and easy way to manage your project's Python dependencies; etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you're running your script. If you want the script to be living in a package (the inner `project` folder), you should run it with `python -m project.process`, rather than by filename. Then you can make absolute or explicit relative imports to get `config` from `process`.

An absolute import would be `from project import config` or `import project.config`.

An explicit relative import would be `from . import config`.

Python 2 also allows implicit relative imports, but they're a really bad misfeature that you should never use. With implicit relative imports, internal package modules can shadow top-level modules. For instance, a `project/json.py` file would hide the standard library's `json` module from all the other modules in the package. You can tell Python you want to forbid implicit relative imports by putting `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the file. It's the standard behavior in Python 3.

Comment: Am I overcomplicating this by treating it like an installable python app? It's an internal application for our company and does not get distributed to lots of users, even internally. Do you think it's good practice to always treat relatively large python projects as installable packages?